# message sent to deallocated instance - program halts

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm running into some strange behavior on xcode. I don't get an error exactly, but the code execution halts at `bkpt   #207` giving no stack trace.

In my program I popToRootViewController whenever tabs are switched. The above behavior occurs after I pop from MyViewController (which is 3rd in stack) programmatically and then click on the tab again. I can confirm that MyViewController is being popped correctly.

With NSZombiesEnabled, I get the following output:

`*** -[MyViewController tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6a4a00`

My hunch is that some remnant of MyViewController is still linked to that tabbar. I'm using [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:kOtherTab] to switch tabs programmatically.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you initialize the `MyViewController`, and do you keep the reference to the controller somewhere?

Comment: ```MyViewController``` gets initialized by initWithCoder (Storyboarding) and no I'm not keeping a reference to the controller anywhere

Answer (score 4):

I got the halts at bkpt #207 for calling to a NSTimer:

```
[Timer invalidate];
[Timer release];
```

correct is only calling

```
[Timer invalidate];
```

and the halts at bkpt #207 disappear.

- invalidate includes the release.
- One would expect to get a SIGABRT or an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error for sending release to a non existant object.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the tableview for some reason is calling it's delegate (MyViewController) after the delegate has been dealloced.

The best thing to do here would be for MyViewController to set the tableView's delegate to nil when it gets dealloced.

Comment: but any idea why its happening so. In my view controller I have used fetchresultscontroller and I clean the DB before dealloc.